# Android:relative layout center things in their own space

Tags: android, center, android-relativelayout

I'm new to android and I would like to achieve something like this, where all thins are centered in their own space.

[representative image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21uWV.png)

I've this code... How can I change it, and why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    tools:context="se.avatarcontrol.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weather"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/light"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="RAINY" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/light"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Light OFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/frontText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/sideText"
        android:text="FrontView"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sideText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/light"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="SideView" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/frontImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android: android:layout_below="@id/frontText"
        android:src="**somesource**" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sideImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/sideText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="**othersource**"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Another thing would be how can my ImageViews fill all the space whithout overlapping each other?

Comment: Please make the question title more specific. This title will get you downvotes

Comment: you should constraint layout, this is what google suggests to prevent unnecessary nesting of layouts.

Answer (score 0):

please use FrameLayout or LinearLayout because it's lighter than RelativeLayout.

To achieve what you want, you should do something like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- Weather light Layout-->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Light" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <!-- Front + Image Layout-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Front" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Image" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Side + Image Layout-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Side" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Image" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

This is the structure. Just adapt your padding / margin / ids and layout_height and width. For your case, i used layout_weight which is useful to specify a size ratio between multiple views.

Comment: @Gohan14 Can you please mark my answer as correct if it helps you :)